# Problem with distribution of workload and data classification (qualitative nominal)

Tags: directory, microsoft-teams, distribution, document-classification, workload

I have a problem in my department and it is getting out of control. I am trying to use Microsoft teams for it.

[image]

Thank you in advance everyone!
Cheers!
Best regards
Edward

Comment: Hi @eoam13, 
Could you please elaborate the question, how you are using Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Hi Rama-MSFT, thanks your response. I have created a channel for each customer and within the channel we use planner for the topics. The problem with this approach is that most of the time, a tech issue is affecting more than one customer. I though about doing it by tech issue but there are too many to open channels for them. Any other topic you'd like clarification?

Comment: We got an idea about the issue, but would request you share us the issue that you technically facing.

Comment: could you please share us the issue that you technically facing.